# viewing an xml node in a WebBrowser Control

Tags: xml, webbrowser-control

i have an xml node like : `<body> <message>ffff</message></body>` how can i view this node in a component so it will desplayed like an xml file (with colors ...) and not like a simple text?

Comment: "component"? What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. found it! need to write this to an xml file and then to write `WebBrowser wb=new WebBrowser(); wb.Navigate(FILEPATH);`

Comment: isn't there any way except write content in a file?